# Google Fit verification team asks us to brand a toggle switch but how?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-fit

We have a flutter android app that uses Google Fit health data
The user has to toggle a switch in order to connect his Google Fit account
We submitted our app to the Google Fit verification process (Trust and Safety team) and they asked us to follow the branding guidelines for the toggle switch.
I don't understand what we're supposed to do and how to brand a toggle switch

Here's the verification team message :
"The toggle switch initiates the OAuth Sign-in process, it is required to comply with the  Google Fit branding guidelines.Please update any links and/or buttons on your application that initiate the OAuth Sign-in process to comply with our policies.

Reply to this email with a NEW YouTube demo video or screenshot showcasing that you've made this update to continue with the verification process."

They also made a screenshot of our video, add added the red arrow, see attached image
[Settings screen - Google Fit toggle switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrQyu.png)

I first replied to them indicating that we have to use a toggle switch in order to allow users to disconnect their Google Fit account (this is also a requirement in their branding guidelines), but they just replied with the same requirement with no further details.

Anyone has an idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After a couple emails and several wasted days, we finally decided to create a new dedicated google fit screen with all the necessary branding and a "Connect to Google Fit" button.
I still don't get why they rejected us, as there are many apps out there with toggle buttons to connect and disconnect from Google Fit